# Check whether a given String is palindrome or not without using any library without loop

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked in an interview to write code to check if a given string is a palindrome or can be a palindrome by altering some character without using a library function. Here is my Approach

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrom {
    static int  temp=0;
    static char[] cArr;
        static boolean chackPotentialPalindrom(char[] cAr){
            cArr=cAr;
            if(cArr!=null){
                char current=cArr[0];
                for(int i=1;i<cArr.length;i++){
                    if(current==cArr[i]){
                        cArr=removeElement(i);
                        chackPotentialPalindrom(cArr);
                        break;
                    } 
                    }
                if(cAr.length==2){
                if(cAr[0]==cAr[1]){
                    cArr=null;
                }}
                if(temp==0 && cArr!=null){
                    temp=1;
                    cArr=removeFirstElement(cArr);
                    chackPotentialPalindrom(cArr);
                    }
                }
            if(cArr==null){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        static char[] removeFirstElement(char[] cAr){
            cArr=cAr;
            if(cArr!=null){
            if(cArr.length >1){
            char[] cArrnew=new char[cArr.length-1];
            for(int j=1,k=0;j<cArr.length;j++,k++){
                cArrnew[k]=cArr[j];
            }
            return cArrnew;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
        }
        static char[] removeElement(int i){
            if(cArr.length>2){
            char[] cArrnew=new char[cArr.length-2];
            for(int j=1,k=0;j<cArr.length;j++,k++){
                if(i!=j){
                    cArrnew[k]=cArr[j];
                }else{
                    k-=1;
                }
            }
            return cArrnew;}
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true){
                temp=0;
            String s=scn.next();
            char[] arr=s.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(chackPotentialPalindrom(arr));
            }
        }
    }
```

Any tips to optimize this code?I could not write this in an interview as they have given a pen and paper to code.It took 3 hrs for me to write this. Can I be a developer?

Comment: This community is not intended for reviewing working code. But beyond that, such interview questions are just one mean to get an idea about a person in short term. For me, your reaction to sit down for three hours to solve the problem (just because you wanted to understand it) and the fact that you now look to others to further improve your solution... Such behavior is what I expect from a future software developer. So: you are doing fine, don't worry!

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat....I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: The only way to check for palindrome without loops is to use recursion

Comment: Beyond that: the thing that I dislike about your code is mostly related to naming. Don't abbreviate, don't put "types" into variable names. Don't call it "cAr", why not charatetsToCheck", potentialPalindrome or something like that...

Comment: Thanks again @GhostCat...I will make sure these kind of mistake never happens again...

Comment: Never say never. Learning never ends!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Title says "without loop" but you need to check all symbol pairs, so using recursion, as you have tried, looks reasonable. But you don't check and use results of recursive calls.

Pseudocode might look like (note we don't need to change source data or extract substring):

**Edit** to provide possibility to alter one char

```
boolean checkPotentialPalindrom(char[] cAr, start, end, altcnt){
       if (end <= start)
             return true

       if (cAr[start] != cAr[end])
            altcnt = altcnt + 1

       if (altcnt > 1) 
             return false

       return checkPotentialPalindrom(cAr, start + 1, end - 1, altcnt)
 }
```

and make the first call with arguments `0, len(cAr-1), 0`

Comment: why did you call it pseudocode? with few `;` added it should be plain Java code

Comment: That is a trick only experienced so folks now about: when you claim "pseudo code" nobody expects it to be completely typo free. Put down real code, and some overcritical person downvotes you for some stupid typo or badly chosen name.

Comment: @Maxim I was not sure that my Java code will be correct

Comment: Clear now. It make sense

Comment: @MBo your code is correct, `int start, int end` and `;` . but you are not checking possible palindrom word by rearanging characters of a word as asked. can you finish that?

Comment: @The Scientific Method You are right, I missed this request when wrote my answer. Added.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your first question..You have to use recursion to solve this problem. Here is my approach.

```
public boolean isPalindrom(char[] str, int start, int end) {
    if (end <= start)
        return true;
    if (str[start] != str[end] || arraySize(str) <= 1)
        return false;
    return isPalindrom(str, start + 1, end - 1);
}

public int arraySize(char[] str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char i : str) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You have tried to implement this algorithm using loops and you can simplify it like this

```
public boolean isPalindroms(char[] str) {
    int diffCount = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = arraySize(str) - 1;

    while (right > left) {
        if (str[right--] != str[left++]) {
            diffCount++;
        }
    }
    return (diffCount < 2);
}

public int arraySize(char[] str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char i : str) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The answer for the second question that you have ask is definitely you can be a good developer. **Computer programming is a Craft. Not Some Kind of Rocket Science.** You have to master it by crafting it.

Comment: Thank you @Aravinda. I really appreciate your contribution towards me.

Answer (score 0):

using recursive function

calling with `left=0 and right = arr.length-1`

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(char[] arr, int left, int right){
    if(arr[left++] != arr[right--])
        return false;
    if(left < right)
        isPalindromss(arr, left++, right--);
    return true;        
}
```

if you have to use while loop, you can simplify it like following

```
public boolean isPalindrom(char[] arr){
    int left=0;
    int right = arr.length-1;
    while(left < right){
        if(arr[left++] == arr[right--])
            continue;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using `StringBuilder`, We can do it

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(String str, int len){
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(str);       
    if((len > 1) & !(sb.substring(0,len/2 + 1).equals(sb.reverse().substring(0,len/2 + 1))))    
        return false;       
    return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function palin(input, leftIdx = 0, rightIdx = input.length - 1) {
  if (leftIdx >= rightIdx) return true;

  if (input[leftIdx] != input[rightIdx]) return false;

  return palin(input, leftIdx + 1, rightIdx - 1);
}

const testCases = {
  air: false,
  airia: true,
  caria: false,
  a: true,
  bb: true,
  bcdb: false,
  zzaaaaz: false,
};

Object.keys(testCases).forEach(test =>
  console.log("Test: ", test, " is palindrome: ", palin(test), testCases[test])
);
```